# Setting up debug listener for PHP Debug in VS Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am setting up VS Code for use with PHP and debugging, with the aim of having the ability to set breakpoints, refresh the page, and stop when it hits them (I know it's possible, but don't know how)

There are no errors/outputs apart from "nothing happens"

As it stands, I have the following set up;

- Windows 11 home
- Xampp v3.2.4 (manual upgrade of PHP from 8.0.3 has been done)
- PHP Version 8.1.10
- XDebug installed (used the wizard with `phpinfo()`)
- [PHP Debug extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xdebug.php-debug) added to VS Code
- launch.json added to a .vscode folder in my root directory

Xampp has ports for 80 and 443 for apache, and neither of these work
Other pages have suggested port 9003 which also does not work

To try and enable this, I have the following inside of my launch.json;

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
    ]
}
```

And a previous attempt (along with many others) was the following;

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Listen For XDebug",
            "port": 80,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/": "${workspaceRoot}"
            },
            "xdebugSettings": {
                "max_children": 256,
                "max_data": -1,
                "max_depth": 5
            },
            "runtimeExecutable": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

My php.ini has the following settings;

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\xampp\tmp"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end, this was an ini issue on the PHP end.

Using the same `launch.json` (changing port to `9003`) config from above, and changing `php.ini` to be;

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.discover_client_host=On
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.mode = trace, debug
xdebug.collect_assignments = true
xdebug.collect_return = true
```

Seems to resolve the issue

Comment: **1)** `xdebug.profiler_enable=1` and `xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\xampp\tmp"` -- its Xdebug v2 options, they do nothing in Xdebug v3. See https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide if you need them. **2)** `xdebug.client_port = 9003` can be omitted as it's a default value. **3)** `xdebug.mode=debug` can be removed as later you have `xdebug.mode = trace, debug`

Comment: *"Using the same launch.json (changing port to 9003)"*. Yes, using `"port": 9000` or `"port": 80` was wrong -- it's a debugger port not a web server.

Comment: Cheers for that, and I have done some of these changes already (didn't know about the output_dir being v2 though!)

Comment: `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` is what helped you here the most. With this setting Xdebug tries to debug **every single request**. Without it you need to provide "debug me" flag sent with the request (Xdebug cookie or GET/POST parameter) -- https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug#activate_debugger

Comment: *"(didn't know about the output_dir being v2 though!)"* It's **profiler_output_dir** in v2. just **output_dir** is v3 name. If you check Xdebug section in `phpinfo()` output you will see a note there. `xdebug_info()` does not have that (and only present in v3)